# Close DropDown of RibbonComboBox on Button Click

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I am having a simple WPF Ribbon Window using RibbonControlsLibrary.

In this Window I am having a RibbonComboBox which contains an Button Element. My intent is to close RibbonComboBox' dropdown once the Button is clicked. I do not want manipulate the IsOpen property of the RibbonComboBox, since the Button should be reused for different purposes. My idea was to handle the MouseDown event of the button and then set e.Handled to false

The XAML looks like this

```
<ribbon:RibbonWindow x:Class="WpfRibbonApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfRibbonApplication3"
        Title="MainWindow"
        x:Name="RibbonWindow"
        Width="640" Height="480">

    <ribbon:Ribbon>
        <ribbon:RibbonTab Header="Home">
            <ribbon:RibbonGroup Header="Group1">
                <ribbon:RibbonComboBox>
                    <ribbon:RibbonGallery>
                        <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory>
                            <ribbon:RibbonGalleryItem>
                                <my:CustomButton Content="Test" />
                            </ribbon:RibbonGalleryItem>
                        </ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory>
                    </ribbon:RibbonGallery>
                </ribbon:RibbonComboBox>
            </ribbon:RibbonGroup>
        </ribbon:RibbonTab>
    </ribbon:Ribbon>
</ribbon:RibbonWindow>
```

The code behind looks as follows:

```
public CustomButton()
{
    // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
    AddHandler(MouseDownEvent,(RoutedEventHandler)Button_MouseDown,true);
}

private void Button_MouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("MouseDownEvent, e.Handled = {0}", e.Handled));
    e.Handled = false;
}
```

The event gets fired but the Ribbon dropdown closes only when pressing the button the second time. Interestingly, the second time I press the button the MouseDown event handler does not get invoked. Can someone give me some hints on how to achieve closing of the ribbon on the first click in a clean manner?

Answer (score 0):

You can give your `RibbonComboBox` a name, let's say `x:Name="comboBox"`, then in the code behind in the mouse down event handler, you can simply do: `comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = false;`

Comment: As I wrote, I do not want to explicitly access the underlying combobox, so this is not the answer to my question.

Comment: My understanding is that the button will be reused in different places. However, handling the click event in the code behind of MainWindow and accessing the ComboBox has nothing to do with the reusability of the button. The event handling part only applies to that particular button instance. Unless you are talking about reusing the particular button instance here.

Comment: Sorry, my original example was too simple. I updated my question. Yes, I want to reuse a custom button class.